# Access IVsFontAndColorDefaults to read complete existing VS theme information

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am new at working on a Visual Studio extension.  I would like to access the complete font and color information for the current theme using C#  I want to access this as a [AllColorableItemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.allcolorableiteminfo?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) structure as this structure includes more information (e.g. flags and the localized name) for the each item. I believe that I need to use [IVsFontAndColorDefaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsfontandcolordefaults?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) interface to do this but I don't know how to get this.  This is probably easy but I cannot figure out how to do it.  I very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are probably on the wrong track IVsFontAndColorDefaults. The documentation seems to indicate, that this is an interface a Visual Studio Package would implement, rather than use itself.

I have some code which accesses the colors used in Visual Studio. It is based almost exactly on [this article by Carlos Quintero](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008008.aspx). The code is in VB.NET, but it would be easy to port to C#.

Alternatively, you might find what you are looking for in the interface IVsFontAndColorStorage.

You can get that interface with code like

```
IVsFontAndColorStorage fontAndColorStorage =
    GetService(typeof(SVsFontAndColorStorage)) as IVsFontAndColorStorage;
```

which I took from this posting [this posting on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269241/how-to-use-ivsfontandcolorevents)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  However, using IVsFontAndColorStorage will get ColorableItemInfo[] structures.  I've worked out how to access this information using this interface.  However, the IVsFontAndColorDefaults interface will access AllColorableItemInfo[] structures and it is the data in this structure I am trying to access as this structure includes flags, type info, and the friendly name for the item.  I am afraid that you are correct though that I cannot get access to this interface and therefore cannot access this data.